# Creating an extensible UI system using Androids Jetpack Compose and Themes

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm new to Jetpack Compose and I've come across custom theming, which looks like the perfect solution for my use case.

At my Company we have a new UI system, where we have reusable components like buttons, textviews, error screens, list items etc.  And these items each come in flavours, and most of them have the same flavours; so for example an expressive button, expressive textview, dark-expressive screen, etc.  These styles include typography, colors, layout parameters, element rounding etc.

Each component is built from a different UI elements or combination of elements. Most of the elements are still relatively simple, comprised of texts, 2 - 4 item layouts, and spacers.  I would like to create a design system using Themes. So far though; I don't think it is powerful enough for my needs.

I would like to create a system that would allow people with no compose experience use a chainable UI to create whatever they need.  For example, you would have something like this.

```
LayoutWith().XButton(withIcon(Resource), withLabel("Some String")
```

This is straightforward enough.  The problem is then the question of applying the theme.

The best scenario would be to able to create a hierarchy.  There would be a base theme with all of the Color options,  Typography options and all of the spacing options. Then we could create children of the different subtypes, so an expressive child, muted child, etc, and then the components.  So the tree would look like this

```
/
└── Pallette
    ├── Expressive
    │   ├── Button
    │   ├── Text
    │   ├── MultiLineListItem
    │   ├── SingleLineListItem
    │   └── ErrorScreen
    └── Muted
        ├── Button
        ├── Text
        ├── MultiLineListItem
        ├── SingleLineListItem
        └── ErrorScreen
```

Each button like the MutedButton would also be able to create a new style using modifiers, and the items that are layouts could have methods like ModifyIcon1, ModifyText1 etc.

Now for the single components this looks pretty straightforward, but I'm not sure about the components that are build from other components.  I understand that with compose themes you can apply a theme to a composable and it will propagate to the child items; but it doesn't look like you can create a base theme and then create new themes by adding or overriding elements.

Can anyone give me an idea of how I would implement this? Or perhaps point me in the right direction to a sample of something like this?

On option would be to build the layout and then be able to apply one or more themes. so you'd have

```
LayoutWith().XButton(withIcon(Resource), withLabel("Some String").applyTheme(Expressive())
```

You could even possibly specify which themes go with which items

```
LayoutWith().XButton(withIcon(Resource), withLabel("Some String").applyTheme(Expressive(Buttons, Icons)).applyTheme(Muted(ErrorScreen))
```

However I give it about a 1% that something like this would ever be needed and seems needlessly complex

If anyone can point me into the direction of some design paradigms that could help it would also be great

Can I add dynamically generated values or business logic in my Themes?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "use a chainable UI to create whatever they need" - I'd suggest dropping this design entirely as it is entirely counter to how you build UIs in Compose. Compose certainly has support for [building your own custom design system](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/custom), but it is applied via the use of `YourTheme` wrappers which apply composition locals which custom components like `YourButton` would be able to read to get theme related attributes from. The more you fight the system, the worse your developer experience will be.

Comment: Ok point taken.  Can I create any value and any type for the LocalContext & LocalProvider?  What about creating components that respond to a custom theme attribues

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what those docs I linked show you how to do.

Comment: Ok so if I wanted to create a custom attribute for theme like Row Height, BigSpacer,  BigLayout, etc.  From the documentation it looks like the themes are restricted to Colors, Typography & Shapes.

Comment: Isn't that [what the fully custom design system section](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/custom#implementing-fully-custom) specifically talks about? "However, design systems are not limited to the concepts Material relies on. You can modify existing systems and introduce entirely new ones — with new classes and types — to make other concepts compatible with themes."